# Change submit onclick based on a checkbox

Tags: javascript

I have a form that is being used as a basic contact form. I have added a checkbox that adds some fields if selected. How can I change the onclick action of the submit button based on if this box is checked or not. Here is what I have currently.

```
<form  class="homeContact"> 
        <label for="chkJob">
            Interested in a career? Check to apply
            <input type="checkbox" id="chkJob" />
        </label>
        <div id="dvApply" style="display: none">

            <a href="" class="application-button" target="_blank">Download Application</a>
                Download the application. Fill it out and upload below:
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        </div>

        <div id="popErr"></div>
        <input type="hidden" name="nospam">
        <div class="field">  
        <div class="label-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name *" value="" name="name" id="popName"> 
        <span class="form-icon fa fa-user"></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">  
        <div class="label-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email *" value="" name="email" id="popEmail"> 
        <span class="form-icon fa fa-envelope"></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">  
        <div class="label-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone *" value="" name="phone" id="popTel">
        <span class="form-icon fa fa-phone"></span>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submit_button">
        <input type="button" class="button submit" id="contact-submit" onclick="submitForm()" value="Request Information">
        </div>
     </form>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#chkJob").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#dvApply").show();
        } else {
            $("#dvApply").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
// true if checked, false if unchecked `
is this what you need?

Comment: *How can I change the onclick action of the submit button based on if this box is checked or not* - The question and your JS code are not related !

Comment: The question is different from the code. I think you are asking how to show/hide an area based on the check mark and not the submit button action. If so [this codepen I did may help](https://codepen.io/tanyagupta/pen/xyxvLa)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this login into your submitForm function:

```
function submitForm()
{
    if ($('#chkJob').is(":checked")) {
        $("#dvApply").show();
    } else {
        $("#dvApply").hide();
    }
}
```

But if you want `dvApply` to be toggled every time checkbox button is clicked without waiting for submit button to be clicked you can do something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#chkJob').change(function() {
        $('#dvApply').toggle();
    });
});
```